# How to print random numbers from a selected sequence?

Tags: arrays, c, random

I want the program to print randomly one of these numbers:

```
{1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,7,7,7,7,8,8,8,8,9,9,9,9,10,10,10,10}
```

Instead it prints randomly nonsense numbers

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
  srand( time(NULL) );
  int card;
  int deck[40] = {1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,7,7,7,7,8,8,8,8,9,9,9,9,10,10,10,10};
  card = rand()% deck[40];
  printf("%d", card);
  return 0;
}
```

What can I do?
thanks

Comment: `deck[40]` is beyond the end of the `deck` array.

Comment: `card = deck[rand() % 40];` would pick one of the 40 cards from `deck` randomly (ignoring a small bias caused by the naive use of `rand() % N`).

Answer (score 2):

This simple way to do this is

```
card = deck[rand() % 40]
```

This way you are picking a 'random' index in the 40 numbers of your array.
Even tho with this array you have the same probability on every number.You can change the balance by changing the array.

Comment: [You don't actually have the same probability on every number unless (RAND_MAX % 40) != 0](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10984974/2166798)